# Should I use "in between" or "inbetween" in the following sentence?

Tags: prepositions, compounds

> You grow old and die anyway. And then there's everything you have to
>   endure **in between/inbetween**: grief, loneliness, sickness.

What's the correct choice? And why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Between* on its own is a preposition while *in-between* functions more like an adverb.

We usually use *between* before the object it refers to:

> Between life and death is a long, hard life.

*In-between* normally comes after the thing it refers to, like in your example.

Here is another example using *in between*:

> I couldn't find my key anywhere, not under the sofa or the chair next to it. Then as I stood up, I saw it glistening in between.

Comment: Are you saying "In between" is a preposition while "in-between" is an adverb? - Sorry just trying to clarify.

Comment: In-between usually functions as an adjective. I actually think the last example should be *in between*, since it is a prepositional usage, not *in-between*.

Comment: @SolarLunix - yes. Aaron Brown - you're right. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

*In between* (2 words) is the correct punctuation for an adverbial phrase, which is how the phrase functions in your sentence. It's also the correct punctuation for a prepositional phrase (e.g., "I live in between two skyscrapers"), but that usage is unnecessary since you can just substitute "between".

*In-between*, with a hyphen, is used as an adjective ("an in-between realm") or a noun ("neither here nor there but the vast in-between"). These usages are an order of magnitude less common than the adverbial phrase.

*Inbetween*, with neither a space nor a hyphen, is non-standard, as far as I know.

Comment: Doesn't "inbetween" mean "to interpolate motion" in animation?